# Android finished task even when app closed

Tags: android, android-service, android-volley

i have made a chat application in which i have to post data to my server the problem comes when user closed the app data is send but not updated in app i tried using service with sticky but on app close it restart service

i want to update ui even app is closed

```
 StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Method.POST,"-----", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String res) {
                    //update UI data is post
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //error occured due to some prblm
            }
        }){
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> Newobj = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Newobj.put("reciever","tymtupx");
                return Newobj;
            }

            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }
        };
        sr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(sr);
```

Comment: Mean, what you want?

Comment: @NigamPatro i want to update my data even when app is closed

Comment: Currently on data is send to server when app is closed i want to update data also

Comment: what will you do by updating ui when it is not even visible .Update your UI when app is opened again

Comment: Update your UI component in onResume() method of your activity instead of onCreate() method because onCreate() method is skipped when your app comes to foreground from background. [More details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: @VivekMishra actually i am also updating my shared preference that is why